# How to design a class correctly

Tags: java, oop

I have a particular case that I don't have really clear how to move to code.

Let's say I have a class "Survey". The survey has an array of "Question"s. I also have a class "Person". Finally there are the answers to those questions that are gathered in a "Answer" class.

The "Person" has associated a "Survey" and an array of "Answer"s (where each answer has associated a question).

So my question is, is this the correct way to do it? I think the design is lousy and I am not separating concerns pretty well.

I can say that both the "Survey" and the "Answer"s objects shouldn't be members of "Person".

And I should create a third object that gathers the information between the "Person", the "Answer" and the "Survey".
Although, this approach sounds like Relational-entity theory using a table to make a M:N:S relation in the end.

What should I do? What do you think it could be a nice/good approach?

Thanks.

Here's the code in Java. Forget about Encapsulation.

```
class Person{
    String name;
    String age;
    Survey survey;
    Answers[] answers;
}

class Survey{
    Question[] listOfQuestions;
}

class Question{
    String questionString;
}

class Answer{
    Question question;
    String answer;
}
```

Comment: 1. Decide which language you are using. 2. Replace handwaving with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, what you want to achieve.

Good approach is to start with system as simple as possible without any redundant information.

For example for basic "forum" - you have "question" and users can "answer" that question. To store all information, you dont have to have list of answers in users class.

However - when you want to show all the answers for concrete user, you have to check all the answers that exists, which is inefficient. This is what is redundant information good for.

---

In your case : It is not possible that `Person` have associated `Survey` and neither `Survey` or `Person` have connection to each other. But maybe it is misunderstanding what you really want to say.

Lets consider, that you want to do very simple StackOverflow.com.

Survey is tag (for each tag you have some questions)
Question, Answer and Person are well known what they are.

Then the minimum requirement is :

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
}

class Survey {
    Question[] listOfQuestions;
}

class Question {
    String questionString;
    Person person;
    Answer[] answers;
}

class Answer {
    Person person;
    String answer;
}
```

However, when you create only one-to-many dependency without "look" from other side, you have all the information, but it can be difficult to obtain it.

On StackOverflow, you want to show all the answers or all the questions for concrete user. Without Person having list of answers/questions, it is difficult to obtain (you have to check all the questions and answers), so it is good idea to add it to person, if you want to user that future.

---

For Survey as "paper" (see in comments): Between person and answer, it should be useful to have link from both sides, therefore allowing finds all answers easily for concrete user. But when you find all the answers for person, you have to have easy access to related question to concrete answer, so you need both side connection too.

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
    Answer[] answers;
}

class Survey {
    Question[] listOfQuestions;
}

class Question {
    String questionString;
    Answer[] answers;
}

class Answer {
    Person person;
    Question question;
    String answer;
}
```

Actually I dont think you really need any direct connection between Survey and Person

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. Though this would be a perfect fit for a forum as you said, but it'd be different if we think of the Survey as a paper with questions that you answer one by one. Think for exmaple, an enterprise wants to query their employees about the satisfaction they have about working in the enteprise. A survey is gven to each employee. They ask to fill in the questions so they know what things can improve in the factory, what working hours would be better for the employees, what salary may be more fair...

Comment: Hmm, and are we interested only in answers or we would like to know, who writes that? (thus the link between Answer and Person is not needed)

Comment: We like to know both the answer and the person who wrote it. But the question itself can only be in one survey (theoritically). Answers are not multiple choice, but free to say whatever you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that looks well. The thing is I was looking for a way around to avoid the person from holding a reference to the answers (so we can separate concerns correctly and assign the members to the correct objects) and create a third class that manages the user, the question and the answer (kind of a Model class) so that we can avoid mingling things that do not belong to certain objects. But perhaps that solution does not exist or is kind of "weird" (weird we might say?). Anyways If you come up with another solution (aka Design Pattern), I'd be glad to hear it :)